# How to make a raspberry pi zero recognisable with tty from linux?

Tags: linux, pi-zero-w

I am trying to configure a raspberry pi zero w to be used through the screen function on linux. In order to achieve this, I have to make it recognisable through tty. It is supposed to be recognised as ttyUSBX or ttyACMX(with X a number). However, when I connect it to my computer with kali and I type:

```
ls /dev/tty*
```

There isn't any ttyUSBX nor ttyACMX appearing. What should I do ?

The Raspberry is used with Raspberry pi OS lite. The micro-b cable is the same I use with my graphic tablet so I suppose it can transfer data. I flashed the micro SD card with another OS and no success. I use the USB port and not the PWR IN port. I tried with another computer and it is still not detected. Nothing new apprears after plugging the Rpi when I type:

```
dmesg
```

Comment: Please read the section [here](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/) titled *Is Kali Linux Right For You?*

Comment: `What should I do ?` ... stop using Kali until you have enough Linux experience to answer your own question

Comment: *"I am trying to configure a raspberry pi zero w to..."* -> You should edit into the question what exactly you have done.  People are more willing to correct mistakes than regurgitate "how-tos" that already exist and presumably you have already read.